# What can you do with a PyDictValues_Type?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, python-c-api

While trying to convert some Python/C API code to work in both 2 & 3, I found that, given the following Python

```
DICT = { … }

class Example(object):
  ITEMS = DICT.values()
```

and then calling `PyObject_GetAttrString(an_example, "ITEMS")` would yield a `PyObject` for which `PySequence_Check` would return true in 2.7. Now in 3.4, it's yielding a `PyObject` whose type is `PyDictValues_Type` and `PySequence_Check` doesn't return true. The documentation on `PyDictValues` is, ahem, sparse. What can one do with it? It also response false to `PyIter_Check`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, `dict.values()` returns a list, but in Python 3, it's a view of dictionary values. The equivalent in Python 2.7 is [`dict.viewvalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

In particular views are not sequences because dictionaries don't have orders. So `dict.viewkeys()` and `dict.viewitems()` are set-like, because keys have to be unique. `dict.viewvalues()` is multi-set-like. You can iterate over it, get the length, and do contains checks against it. But you can't index into it like a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Basically just `iter` (`PyObject_GetIter` in the C API).

There are technically other operations, like `==` (inherited from `object`, uninteresting), `len` (but you'd call that on the dict instead of making a values view if you wanted that), and `in` (slow, linear scan, avoid it), but the primary use of a values view is as an iterable.

If you want a list, like Python 2, using the C API call `PyDict_Values` on the dict instead of calling the `values` method still makes a list.

Keys and items views (`keys()` and `items()`) are more interesting. They support all the operations in the [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) interface, which you'd access through the usual C API equivalents of those operations (so things like `PyObject_RichCompare` or `PySequence_Contains`, even though they're not sequences).

Comment: In my case an iter was all I needed, so the top of this worked for me. `PyDict_Values` on that object returned `nullptr`.

Comment: @NathanHerring: `PyDict_Values` takes the dict, not a dict values object.